# Problem with integration between snap and apt programs

Tags: apt, snap

Wherever I had a web link in a snap-provided application, I can't open it directly on Firefox (or other browsers, like Chrome). This is happening with Skype, VSCode and Discord (all 3 installed via snap)

Comment: Hi! It is not clear what you mean by _link_. There are _symbolic links_ in Linux but you probably do not mean that.

Comment: Hi @user4124. Thank for your reply. By a link I meant a link to a web site. I'm still with the same problem, except that VSCode is actually working well. It's like snap apps have a local environment and don't integrate with the environment defined on my home folder

Comment: I see. Those specific snap packages appear not to respect the system's settings for _Default browser_. This is likely a packaging issue for those snap packages. 
I am using the snap package for Firefox, and when you try to open a downloaded file, it prompts you with a wizard (from the snap package) to let you select the handler.